# javascript - seeking satisfying explanation of why anonymous function wrapper needed in callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

I know that this works:

```
$("#btn_1").click(function() {
  alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
});
```

While this just pops up the alert dialog prematurely:

```
$("#btn_1").click(alert("Btn 1 Clicked"););
```

My Q is: in the second case, why doesn't the alert wait for the ***click*** before executing?

Comment: Consider `alert(someFunc())` - which function runs first, `alert()` or `someFunc()`? Now consider `alert(someFunc(anotherFunc()))`...

Comment: remember `PEMDAS` from middle school? the `P` applies here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you call a function, the arguments are executed immediately to provide the parameters to pass to the function.

```
func(arg);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var temp = arg;
func(temp);
```

So when you write:

```
$("#btn_1").click(alert("Btn 1 Clicked"));
```

it's equivalent to:

```
var temp = alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
$("#btn_1").click(temp);
```

It should be obvious that in this form, the alert happens before calling `.click()` to add a listener for the event.

In order to delay action, you have to provide a function as the argument. A function definition by itself doesn't cause any of the code to be executed, it only gets executed when it gets called later (this is called a "callback").

It doesn't have to be an anonymous function, you can name it as well.

```
function myAlert() {
    alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
}
$("#btn_1").click(myAlert);
```

But notice that you just provide the name of the function as the argument to `.click()`, you don't write `myAlert()`, because that will call it immediately, not delay until the click event occurs.

As @Titus said, `click()` expects its argument to be a function, because it wants to execute it as a callback. But you can call another function to return a function:

```
function alerter(message) {
    return function() {
        alert(message);
    }
}
$("#btn_1").click(alerter("Btn 1 Clicked"));
```

Notice that `alerter()` doesn't call `alert()` directly, it returns another function that will call `alert()` when it is called. As above, that won't happen until the click event performs its callback.

Comment: I like this answer. And to this I will also add @Titus's explanation (below) that `.click` expects a function as an argument, and not the result of a function.

Comment: @user1883050 - If the result of a function call is a reference to a function then that's fine.

Comment: I've added an example of a function that returns another function.

Comment: Two clarifications requested: (1) "A function definition by itself doesn't cause any of the code to be executed." Why isn't this true for the `alert()` function in `$("#btn_1").click(alert("Btn 1 Clicked"));` then? (2) How come the following rule doesn't apply to the `alert()` inside the callback function: "arguments are executed immediately to provide the parameters to pass to the function"?

Comment: (1) That's not a function definition. (2) Evaluating a function definition doesn't execute the body of the function, it just saves it to be called later. That's the whole point of functions. They aren't executed until you call them.

Comment: I think you need to go read a good programming textbook, and learn the difference between **defining** a function and **calling** a function.

Comment: I think I explained it as clearly as I'm able in my answer. If you don't understand the basics, I'm not going to be able to help you.

Comment: I think I got it now! Function definitions != Function calls

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best explanation I can think of:

```
var alertResult = alert('Btn 1 clicked');
button.addEventListener('click', alertResult); // say waaat?
var alertFunction = function() {
    alert('Btn 1 clicked');
};
button.addEventListener('click', alertFunction); // Yess!
```

Answer (score 1):

The `click(...)` function expects a function as an argument, you're not passing it a function, you're passing it the result of a function.

Consider this: `func(1+2)` the argument to the `func` method will be `3` (the result) not `1 + 2` (the operation itself).

Answer (score 1):

> My Q is: in the second case, why doesn't the alert wait for the click
>   before executing?

You are calling the function.

You can reference the function to call when `event` occurs using either `.bind()`

```
$("#btn_1").click(alert.bind(window, "Btn 1 clicked"));
```